# SQL Server Express with PowerPivot

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, powerpivot

Is it possible to use PowerPivot (in Excel 2013) with SQL Server Express (which version is recommended?)?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very unclear. How do you want to use Power Pivot with SQL Server Express?

Is SQL Server your data source? Then yes. You can connect to any ODBC data source from Power Pivot?

Are you trying to host Power Pivot workbooks on SharePoint? In that case, you need SQL Server BI Edition or Enterprise Edition to host the workbooks.

Are you trying to promote a Power Pivot workbook to a SQL Server Analysis Services model? In that case you also need SQL Server BI Edition or Enterprise Edition.

There is no requirement to have any version or edition of SQL Server around to use Power Pivot on your desktop. Similarly there is no requirement to have any version or edition of SQL Server anywhere on your network/in your organization to use Power Pivot on your desktop. We have clients who happily use SQL Server against Oracle data warehouses as a source.

Comment: Sorry for late reply... No SQL Server is not my data source, I need it mostly to gather and process data from 2-3 different data sources. Also no, I do not intend to host Power Pivot workbooks on SharePoint, I mean to use Excel and create dashboards with Power Pivot providing data. Now I see, that my question is really a bit narrow... Mostly I am interested in finding out about limitations of SQL Express Server when sending the data to my dashboards using Power Pivot.

Comment: Also I noticed in the meanwhile, that for bringing data to SQL Express, I would need to set-up services in the outside, since Express does not support scheduling, right?